# Best way to set cookie for multi-tenant architecture

Tags: javascript, java, angular, spring, cookies

**Need recommendation on my solution**

I am having a multi-tenant product in the *SaaS architecture* means the same API is common for all the clients. so we hosted in the common domain (xyz.com).

but we having N number of frontend client ( ex: abc.com, fb.com, test.com).

we need to store a user's logged info in the token via a cookie. what is the best way to achieve this?

**Problem is:**

Getting invalid domain attribute with regards to the current host URL while setting cookies in the browser. [chrome's F12 window network response screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAiJx.png)

my website is running in abc.com now and API is hosted at xyz.com.

Trying to set a cookie with the domain as abc.com in Ajax call from abc.com to xyz.com, but getting above warring in the browser and cookie is not set.

But if I set the cookie domain as xyz.com, then the cookie is setting in abc.com.

**My Conclusion:**

Brower will accept the cookie only from the API's domain( UI - there is a way to skip - samesite). So I can make my cookie as an HTTP only and secure cookie.

xsrf-token -> will be in http only secure cookie
x-xsrf-token -> will be in local storage

so that it will be safe from XSS and CSRF(Edited)